# How to handle when XMLHttpRequest fails?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, ecmascript-5

I am trying to make an XHR call but if server is not online or if Internet is disconnected after the call is initiated then i get failed as status 
[Network Log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMyEQ.png)

I tried onload(), onerror(), onreadystatechange() events but none of them are fired.
Here is my Javascript snippet

```
function login() {
    animateLogo(true);
    document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "localhost:3000/login";
    var params = `email=${email}&password=${password}&remember=${remember}`;
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onload = function () {
        animateLogo(false);
        // Response handler
    }
    http.send(params); }
```

Since none of the events are fired i am unable to stop my animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for the status of the request
(success = 200, notFound = 404, serverError = 500 etc..)

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "localhost:3000/login";
http.open('POST', url, true);
const params = `email=${email}&password=${password}&remember=${remember}`;
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
    // handle other status here
}
http.send(params);
```